# Angular LocalStorage Securely Storing Express API Data

Tags: angular

Okay So I am having a total disconnect here. I have read article after article on Google and still have not come up with a plausible way to store information from express to angular. So here is how my server is set up.

I first get username and password from angular form and send it to express.

Afterward I receive it in express grab the user info out of the database and send it back to Angular.

From there I store the information locally with localStorage.

My problem is this. Isn't this completely insecure? Can't a user change the variables in their localStorage and possibly spoof another user? (Please bear with me I am new to this).

The only solution I could think of was to use the users ID to verify authenticity when a user does certain things such as send messages and things of that nature.

So I guess my question would be, whats the best way to do this? Am I on the right path? I have literally been looking at articles for days and have been stuck on this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is to put auth payload on request in frontend and validate the payload in backend. You may look for some cases with ng&express&jwt integrated.

Comment: I know this may be difficult but can you explain this to me? When you say payload are you referring to tokens? And if so what would be the best way to do this. I am a complete beginner with tokens and Angular in general so all of this is very new to me.

Comment: [This post](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/) may help you understand JWT-based authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep your users informations after browser (chrome, firefox, IE...) is closed, so next time user starts browsing he doesn't need to login again since he already has his security info, then you must keep data in locale or some other "external" storage.

On the other hand, if you don't mind if users has to login every time he starts browsing, you can create a service in angular and keep your sensitive data there. As long as browser is up and application running that data can be accesed by user, an he can't change it on his own.

Comment: Ok So, how does this service work? I am familiar with services so do I query the api every time the user switches a page and then have the api query the Database? I am just very lost on how to implement something of this sort.

Comment: @Joe Alvini It is simple creation. You need to create a service that will be responsible for all your security issues. Lets call it `auth.service`. In that service you can get and store all data you need. (userRoles, userID, userName etc...). When user login to your app, you get those data from DB and store it in those variables. Later, when your app logout you simply delete values of those variables. When user closes the app thoses variables will be nulled. When you need some of those data in any component, you simply inject `auth.service` in that component and you will have security data.